# Transfer function_Approximation of second order system for a linear actuator

Tags: control, transfer-function, modeling, actuator, non-linear

I am trying to approximate a transfer function of a system. The system is a linear actuator, connected to a feedback potentiometer. The actuator has a mass on it. The following figure is a step response, with 24 V as input, and the potentiometer position as output.[image]

by this, I found out it is totally impossible to approximate this system as a first or second order system. Is there a way to experimentally find an approximation(I mean transfer function) of this behavior?

Comment: If I had a linear actuator with that response I'd want my money back.

Comment: @Andyaka, one day I took the load off, and I did the experiment. I did not see this behavior. however, I saw that it reaches the steady state so fast. Tae is almost nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use give an impulse input to the system. Observe the output, extract the equation and finally take the laplace transform to get the transfer function.